# Mysterious ajax json request problems jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, rss

I want to read an rss feed converted to json format with a google api ; i had put some alerts but i can't see them when i run my page ! Why ?

Here is my jQuery code :

```
function getFeed(url){
        $('#screen #content').html("");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q='+url,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(3);
                $.each(data.entries, function(i,results){
                    alert(1);

                });
            }
        });
    }
    getFeed('http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Science.xml');
```

Thanks !

Comment: if you want to get json with jQuery use $.getJSON .. and register a complete handler .. maybe your request is invalid or something like that (wrong url etc. )

Comment: You might want to url encode `url`

Comment: what's the output in the dev console? have you tryed attaching an error handler an read the error message?

Comment: I have a little message : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
But when i try my js code with jsLint no problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax requests are limited by the browser's Same Origin Policy. You can't talk directly to a server via ajax that isn't on the same domain as the page your script is running in.
So, you need to use the jsonp feature from jquery ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        function getFeed(url) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=' + url,
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
        getFeed('http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Science.xml');

    });
```

dataType: 'jsonp' is the keyword here.

You can read more about it searching 'jsonp' here: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

or here:
http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/

Comment: @Rochester: Be aware that the server has to support JSONP as well. It is not a magic bullet that lets you do cross domain requests to all domains.

Answer (score 0):

1. It can also be possible that the host you are requesting to, doesn't allow third-party or cross-browser ajax calls.
2. If you are expecting JSON as in result from request, use `$.getJSON()`.

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: I already try to use getJson, it works, but why my ajax request dosen't work ?

Comment: try giving your callback function in URL instead. it should work since getJSON() calls $.ajax itself internally.